# rent for three months

Tags: punctuation

I'm drafting a lease which requires tenants to pay rent for the first three months when they sign the lease. Which one of the following is correct? Thanks.

three month rent
three month's rent
three months' rent

Comment: Check out our sister site ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: #2 is correct btw.

Comment: Why is #2 correct?

Comment: The correct answer when drafting a document of this kind is _speak to a solicitor_.

Comment: According to the answers in the link above, there are two correct ways; 1) Three **months** rent. 2) Three **months'** rent.

Comment: Then again, yky a could be a spammer... Doesn't seem to be very responsive :(

Comment: "Rent for the first three months" avoids the issue.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about writing a legal document

Answer (score 0):

The third option - "three months' rent" - since month is plural (there are three of them).